# Could not open a connection to SQL Server after 2017 update

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Sever before version 2016 and have updated. It is 2017 version now.

Now when I open SQL Sever I get this error:

```
Cannot connect to ..

Additional information:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error:
40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

The system cannot find the file specified
```

I entered

- Server Type: Database Engine
- Server name: .
- Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
- Login: sa

Comment: Your server name is a period?

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: Your screenshot shows you're trying to connect to a server named `.` which seems unusual.  Perhaps you simply entered the wrong server name?

Comment: I'm talking about the 'Server name' input.  I am not talking about your username and password.

Comment: What is it you are trying to "open"? You don't "open" a SQL server, you connect to it. You don't open a database file, you attach it to a Server. I cannot recommend enough that you think of a more secure password for your `sa` login. Infact, I recommend you change it right now! DON'T EVER POST YOUR PASSWORD! EVER! Your `sa` account should have a secure password. That account can do **anything**. Back on topic, I'll reiterate what everyone else has said; your server is not called `.`. Try `localhost` (assuming it has the default Instance name and is on the localhost).

Comment: @mrogers It's probably a default instance.  The `.` should work.

Comment: This error means that or server name is incorrect or it's not running. Are you sure it's running? Is it default instance?

Comment: Try going through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502714/intermittent-odbc-connection-failures/52504914#52504914)

Answer (score -2):

Resolution:
While verifying the Services i found that the MSSQLSERVER service was stopped, after starting this service my issue was resolved.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to get familiar with how to use the site.