# Problem when setting up Microsoft SQL as default Database for WSO2 EI

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have followed the steps in this tutorial to setup MS SQL server as my default DB provider for WSO2 EI 6.3.

[Tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+Microsoft+SQL)

below is the log of the error i'm getting (wso2error file):

> TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-18 12:50:47,152] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil} -  Database Error - null
>   {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil} java.sql.SQLException
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:158)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:448)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:124)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
>     ... 31 more TID: [-1234] [] [2018-10-18 12:50:47,167] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User
>   Manager Core bundle {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator}
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the
>   realm.    at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:274)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database
>   Error - null  at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:168)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:448)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:124)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
>     ... 19 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:158)
>     ... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
>     ... 31 more

also, here's master-datasources.xml file

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">

<providers>
    <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
</providers>

<datasources>


<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/wso2carbon</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:sqlserver://ip:1433; databaseName=wso2carbon;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false</url>
                <username>root</username>
                <password>P@ssw0rd@123</password>
                <driverClassName>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>80</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>


  <!-- Commented by Majd -->
    <!-- <datasource> -->
        <!-- <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name> -->
        <!-- <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description> -->
        <!-- <jndiConfig> -->
            <!-- <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name> -->
        <!-- </jndiConfig> -->
        <!-- <definition type="RDBMS"> -->
            <!-- <configuration> -->
                <!-- <url>jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url> -->
                <!-- <username>wso2carbon</username> -->
                <!-- <password>wso2carbon</password> -->
                <!-- <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName> -->
                <!-- <maxActive>50</maxActive> -->
                <!-- <maxWait>60000</maxWait> -->
                <!-- <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow> -->
                <!-- <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery> -->
                <!-- <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval> -->
                <!-- <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit> -->
            <!-- </configuration> -->
        <!-- </definition> -->
    <!-- </datasource> -->

    <!-- For an explanation of the properties, see: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html -->
    <!--datasource>
        <name>SAMPLE_DATA_SOURCE</name>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name></name>
            <environment>
                <property name="java.naming.factory.initial"></property>
                <property name="java.naming.provider.url"></property>
            </environment>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>

                <defaultAutoCommit></defaultAutoCommit>
                <defaultReadOnly></defaultReadOnly>
                <defaultTransactionIsolation>NONE|READ_COMMITTED|READ_UNCOMMITTED|REPEATABLE_READ|SERIALIZABLE</defaultTransactionIsolation>
                <defaultCatalog></defaultCatalog>
                <username></username>
                <password svns:secretAlias="WSO2.DB.Password"></password>
                <maxActive></maxActive>
                <maxIdle></maxIdle>
                <initialSize></initialSize>
                <maxWait></maxWait>

                <dataSourceClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</dataSourceClassName>
                <dataSourceProps>
                    <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test1</property>
                    <property name="user">root</property>
                    <property name="password">123</property>
                </dataSourceProps>

            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource-->

</datasources>
```

please advise, thanks.

Comment: Can you try connecting via UI, log into wso2 EI, go to configure-->Datasources, Enter DB details and then click on "Test connection", if the connection is healthy then there is no connectivity issue

Comment: thanks. I tried the UI, i'm getting this when testing the connection : com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: I'm not sure if this would help, but I think you have trouble connecting to SQL.
If that is the case, have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502714/intermittent-odbc-connection-failures/52504914#52504914

Comment: If the test connection didn't get through then your EI instance is having troubles with SQL server.

Comment: Have you tried updating Java to a newer version? This error `com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0` is telling you that it cannot load the SQL Server connector because your Java installation is too old.

Comment: Thanks @Riverchimp, I hope i'm getting this properly. I have (jre1.8.0_191) installed in program files/java, I also, installed the the installer for JDBC (sqljdbc_4.2.8112.200_enu). and i'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Fix

I connected to a remote server with default SQL server instance name instead of [IP]\instance name

i.e. [IP] only.