# Can't connect to SQL Server instance from Windows 10 Only

Tags: sql-server, windows-10

I'm getting an error 10060 when trying to connect to a SQL Server database - but only from **Windows 10**.

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)

I can successfully connect to the server from other PCs with Windows 7 and XP.

I don't know why but the only PCs that don't connect have Windows 10, has anyone had a similar experience?

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Have a look at the answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502714/intermittent-odbc-connection-failures/52504914#52504914)

That will sort you out...

Comment: Check the firewall on your windows 10 machines, and make sure port 1433 outbound is allowed. Also check name resolution. Windows 10 doesn't do older netbios name resolution by default... but that's because you shouldn't be using it anywhere (it's really bad), so if this ends up being the problem check the DNS settings in your environment.

Comment: Also... why are you still using Windows XP? It has been end-of-life for several years now. This means it no longer gets patches... not even critical security updates. It's dangerous and irresponsible to continue having it in service. I know it may be outside your area, but it's time to advocate for replacing those machines. Windows 7 will be in the same boat in only about a year, so it's time to start replacing those machines, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for me was that I had configured Windows Firewall for Domains to block any IN Connections, so I changed it and now it works.
Also not showing screen caps of configuration since I'm Spanish speaker and have windows in Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Check if the SQL Browser service is running:

1. Control Panel
2. Administrative Tools
3. Services
4. The SQL Service Browser is probably Disabled
5. Right click and select Properties
6. Change the Startup type to Automatic (Delayed Start)
7. Click to Start button to start the service

Answer (score 0):

This error could occur because either the **firewall on the server has refused the connection or the server is not configured to accept remote connections**.

**User Action**: from [MSSQLSERVER_10060](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-10060-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-2017)

To resolve this error, try one of the following actions:-

> - Make sure that you have configured the firewall on the computer to allow this instance of SQL Server to accept connections.
> - Use the `SQL Server Configuration Manager` tool to allow SQL Server to accept remote connections.

Comment: As I mention in the question I can connect to the instance in other Pcs that have Windows XP and 7, so I think the real problem is in Windows 10

Comment: I don't think so.. have you configured the firewall on the Windows 10 to allow this instance of SQL Server to accept connections?