# Microsoft Sync Service fails for remote Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017, microsoft-sync-framework

Microsoft Sync Service doesn't work for two different remote Database Server.
When I run the same service on the local server it gets implemented within half an hour. But if I try to implement taking one local server and other remote servers, it fails by executing some small tables. I have tried running service few times it fails with this error. 
"A transport-level error occurred while receiving the server results. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout has expired.)".
What Could be the reason for this?
(Note: Two Server in two different Countries and I am getting a good ping of the remote server, so there is no network issue)

Comment: Have you checked the network settings, etc for SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Have a look at the answer provided in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502714/intermittent-odbc-connection-failures/52504914#52504914)

Comment: doesn't work i tried it

Comment: Did you restart the SQL Servers?

Comment: yup i have done nothing helps

Comment: Did you check to see if any Firewall is blocking SQL? i.e. SQL Server and it's ports : 1433?

Comment: checked it, nothing is blocking it