# How to connect SQL Server by host IP Address

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

I'm trying to connect new host in SQL Server using IP address, but I got some trouble when I'm trying to log in SSMS 2017. I'm still relatively newbie about using SQL Server. **Here's the error message:**

[image: error]

**when I'm trying to login:**

[image: error]

**And here when I check SQLCMD**
[image: error]

> I've been trying:

**1. Restart Service SQL Server**

**2. Enable all Protocols for MSSQLSERVER (include TCP/IP and Named Pipes)**

**3. Allow remote connections**

**4. Enable SQL Server Browser**

Comment: Why do you want to use IP address instead of host name? Either way, if you can connect by hostname,you'll be able to connect by IP. When you use a hostname it's simply the DNS that tells your PC what the IP address is for that host.

Comment: like i said, i'm still newbie. but I'am just copy from .env laravel. 
DB_HOST=10.x.x.1xx
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password.

So I just want to access database from web to SSMS

Comment: Try the answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502714/intermittent-odbc-connection-failures/52504914#52504914). I'm sure it'll sort your problem.

Comment: Still the same, I've been changed the TCP/IP properties. But thanks for the suggest

Answer (score 1):

Check your SQL Server log to ensure that it's listening on the IP address(es) you expect.  You should see an entry during startup like:

```
Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
```