# Can not use servername to login into SQL Sever but tcp ip can

Tags: sql-server

I have this problem: I use another computer to connect to my SQL Server on my computer. But I can't use server name to login, only the IP address. I don't know what causes this, I use port 1444. Any ideas for solving this problem?

The message I get when trying to log in using the server name:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502714/intermittent-odbc-connection-failures/52504914#52504914) to configure your SQL Server Properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try along with the port number

```
servername :192.111.1.121,1444
```

Comment: yes, i can use ip port number to login but i need to use servername's login to distribution database. Suscription can't use port number to login.